# neo4j on Amazon Elastic Cloud Compute

Tags: neo4j

I want to install neo4j on Amazon EC2. I would appreciate if someone can give any useful pointers of what needs to be done. I prefer to use the free micro instance available in Amazon EC2.

Comment: I think the memory requirements for a simple neo4j might be 1gb or larger which unless I'm mistaken is more than what the micro covers.  You could still try to run it on the micro instance - the performance might not be great.

Comment: you can choose to use the neo4j ami's on amazon.  If you wish to install on your own, scp the tar file to the server.  You may have to change the listening ip address or ensure that its running on 0.0.0.0 in the neo4j-server.properties file (conf directory).  Run the process by calling start from /bin/neo4j

Comment: I have tried using embedded Neo4j embedded on EC2 micro instance (613MB RAM). Does work for some time, but very soon jvm runs out of memory (Perm Gen space error specifically) after few web requests are processed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped I managed to get ne04j instance up and running on EC2. However, I would appreciate if you let me know how can I choose ne04j ami's on amazon instead of installing my own.